# How to have a control dynamically appear (after choosing a dropdown option)

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

So say I have a dropdown control, and after the user uses the drop down, I want a checkbox and label to appear, AJAX style, without a full postback.

How can I implement something like this? Examples of code (or links to them) would be great.

I played around with this some using updatepanels but I can't get it working right...

Comment: Why do you need *any* postback just for a checkbox and label to appear?

Comment: true, i just wanted to emphasize that i didn't want to do a postback...guess i could have worded it better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this with something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showOptions(val) {
  $('.option').hide();
  $('.option' + val).show();
}
</script>

<style>
.option { border:solid 1px blue; display: none; }  
</style>

<select id="dropdown" onchange="showOptions(this.value)">
  <option value="1">select an option:</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<div class="option option1">put controls for option 1 here</div>
<div class="option option2">put controls for option 2 here</div>
<div class="option option3">put controls for option 3 here</div>
```

Note: this is using [jquery](http://jquery.com/).

You can see and experiment with a working example here: http://jsbin.com/owoho

Answer (score 2):

I've put together a little example (using jQuery) to help you get started:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    // bind an event handler to the select's change event
    $("#testSelect").change(function() {

        // create a label from the text of the selected option
        var $label = $("<label>" + $(this).text() + "</label>");

        // create a checkbox
        var $checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox"/>');

        // append the label and checkbox to the next div, reveal it with animation
        $(this).next("div")
               .empty()
               .append($label)
               .append($checkbox)
               .show("slow");
    });
});
</script>

<select id="testSelect">
    <option value="foo" selected="selected">Hello</option>
    <option value="test">Wooo</option>
</select>
<div style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: I prefer @Martin's approach of having hidden items on the page and then showing them as necessary. Always better to avoid building markup in code if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you were just wanting to post some data to the server when the dropdownlist changes than i would just use jQuery (my preference).

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown" runat="server" onchange="javascript: ajaxCall();">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Then your javascript could look like this.

```
        function ajaxCall() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/Services.aspx/SomeMethod",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{}", // send some data if you need to
            beforeSend: function() {
              //do some things before the request is made
            },
            success: function(msg) {
                chkBox.show();
                spanOrDivName.show();
            }
        });

       };
```

There are many ways to make an ajax call with jQuery, but I'm using this one because it's the most robust and I'm not sure what else you need it to do.

Comment: I don't think @Albert is asking how to interact with the server here - just how to show & hide controls on the page based on what the user does.

Comment: You may be right, but I added the ajax code because he said he wanted to do it "AJAX style". I saw the other samples that covered what you suggested so I added something different.